# Leaving some space between the 'Contents' heading and the ToC

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, amsart

In `amsart`, how do you leave an additional `\vspace{3mm}` between the heading 'Contents' and the Table of Contents?

Comment: Just for the ToC or alos for the List of Figures and List of Tables, for consistency's sake?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, yes, also for LoF and LoT; thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\def\@starttoc#1#2{\begingroup
  \setTrue{#1}%
  \par\removelastskip\vskip\z@skip
  \@startsection{}\@M\z@{\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}%
    {.5\linespacing}{\centering\contentsnamefont}{#2}%
  \ifx\contentsname#2%
    \vspace{3mm}% Here for the ToC only
  \else \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}\fi
    %\vspace{3mm}% Here for all lists
  \makeatletter
  \@input{\jobname.#1}%
  \if@filesw
    \@xp\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
    \immediate\@xp\openout\csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
  \fi
  \global\@nobreakfalse \endgroup
  \addvspace{32\p@\@plus14\p@}%
  \let\tableofcontents\relax
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\section{Test section}
\begin{figure}
\caption{A test figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\caption{A test table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

use

```
    \vspace{3mm}% Here for the ToC only
```

to add the spacing for the ToC only. Comment out the previous line and uncomment

```
    %\vspace{3mm}% Here for all lists
```

if the addition must be also done for the LoF and the LoT.

Comment: Thanks. How do you do it for LoF and LoT?

Comment: @Ryo My answer already explains (read the final part) how to do it for LoF and Lot.

Comment: Right. Sorry, I didn't see  `%\vspace{3mm}% Here for all lists`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For all ToC-related structures, the following patch from [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) works:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\@starttoc}{.5\linespacing}{5\baselineskip}{}{}
\makeatother
```

It replaces the existing vertical gap (of `.5\linespacing` or 6pt) with `5\baselineskip` (or whatever you choose). If you want to only affect the ToC (and not the LoF or LoT), then you need to place the following before the above patch:

```
\makeatletter
\let\old@starttoc\@starttoc
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\old@starttoc{lof}\listfigurename}
\renewcommand{\listoftables}{\old@starttoc{lot}\listtablename}
\makeatother
```

Here is a complete example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\let\old@starttoc\@starttoc
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\old@starttoc{lof}\listfigurename}
\renewcommand{\listoftables}{\old@starttoc{lot}\listtablename}
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\@starttoc}{.5\linespacing}{5\baselineskip}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\section{A section}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```